# Python list slices as views

Tags: python

I have a list `l` of pairs `(p, q)`, where `q` is a sorted list of unique integers with `len(q) > p`.  I am interested in taking the symmetric difference of all `q[p:]` for `p, q` in `l`.

To that end, I have:

```
def symm_diff(iterables):
    if len(iterables) == 0:
        return
    elif len(iterables) == 1:
        yield from iterables[0]
    else:
        yield from oddly_occurring(heapq.merge(*iterables))
```

where

```
def oddly_occurring(iterable):
    i = iter(iterable)
    j = next(i, None)
    while j is not None:
        k = next(i, None)
        if j == k:
            j = next(i, None)
        else:
            yield j
            j = k
    if j is not None:
        yield j
```

yields the elements that occur an odd number of times in the (sorted) input.

Now I can call `symm_diff(*(q[p:] for p, q in l)`. However, I am wondering if this is smart if the lists `q` are rather long – would issuing `q[p:]` not leave me with a *copy* of the tail of `q`, and not with a “view” on it, as, e.g., numpy does it with slices? Would it be smarter to call `symm_diff` (or a differently designed function) in a different way, given that I have to do this really often?

Comment: Usually it is best to provide a minimal example for the input/data with the [mre]; enough to use for testing - sometimes *seeing* the data combined with the written description helps a lot.

Comment: In this case a short script generating the `list l of pairs (p, q), where q is a sorted list of unique integers with len(q) > p` might also help us create large datasets to test.

Comment: You should devise some tests that will elucidate the strengths or weaknesses of different methods that answers might provide. [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) might be what you want - You could use the tests to help you make a judgement.